Normalizing the embedding space of an encoder language model with respect to categorical data
Suppose we have a tree/hierarchy of categories (e.g. categories of products in an e-commerce website), each node being assigned a title. Assume that the title of each node is semantically accurate, meaning it's consistent with the category (the titles of the children nodes) it represents. Now, take an encoder language model (like BERT or Word2Vec) and produce embeddings for each node/category. My goal is to ensure that these embeddings are representative of the categorical hierarchy. I wonder:

Should the embeddings (mostly) be consistent with the categorical hierarchy, even if the categorical hierarchy is very niche and/or uneven (meaning that categorical granularity is not necessarily evenly distributed, if that makes sense)? By consistent, I mean that the embeddings of sibling nodes under one parent should be closer to each other than to children nodes of other parents, and closer to their parent's embeddings than to other parents' embeddings. Is there a nice metric to measure/validate this?
If not, what would be good ways to re-map a latent space to make it "nicer" with respect to the categorical hierarchy? I'm thinking either 1) we directly transform the latent space or 2) fine-tune the language encoder model (i.e. BERT). For example: 1) let's say that the shape formed by a category/parent's sub-categories/children is a thin oval, would it be possible and make sense to want to map the space such that this thin oval becomes a circle? Also for 2) would fine-tuning BERT along the task of classifying leaf embeddings' under the correct parent embeddings do the same thing?

I think that this requires the categories to not be so niche and to have some correspondence to regular language usage (and even more after providing context), which is my case.
This is just my intuition, so let me know your thoughts. I would be interested in exploring anything from the most simple heuristic approaches to SOTA NLP techniques that could pertain to this problem.
